# add text to end of all links containing something

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add to the end of specific links that contain a certain text.

In my code I found the specific links and changed the beginning of them leaving a variable from the original link. I need to add to the end of that variable. currently at the end of my code I use the append tag but it only adds to link text not the actual link. How can I do this or is there a better way?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a[href^='http://www.1shoppingcart.com/']").each(function () {
        this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/www\.1shoppingcart\.com\/SecureCart\/SecureCart.aspx/,
         "http://www.1shoppingcart.com/SecureCart/Securecart.aspx/onclick = '_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.1shoppingcart.com/SecureCart/Securecart.aspx/");
    });
    $('a[href*=1shoppingcart]').append("']); return false;'");
});
```

Comment: I believe `this.href` is not safe. I recommend you to use jQuery's attr() instead to manipulate the href attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a[href*=1shoppingcart]').attr('href', function(i,v) {
    return v + ']); return false;';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with another `each` call:

```
$('a[href*=1shoppingcart]').each(function () {
  this.href = this.href + ']); return false;';
}
```

That being said, do you really need to do this? It looks like you're adding Google Analytics clicks to links, and it seems like it'd be easy enough to just add a `click` handler to all of your links (instead of modifying the `href` attribute).

Comment: that would make more sense but it's a little above my knowledge. I can add an onclick but the only adding it to certain links is what I have a hard time with

Comment: You'd do it just like you have in your selector - except instead of `.each(function(...`, you'd do `.click(function(...`, and then have whatever code you needed to run in there.